# I want to display table rows in same class and difference function in PHP

Tags: php, function, class, oop, mysqli

how to display rows in my users table in PHP
arr() function can't connect with database

```
class DB {
    protected $db_server = 'localhost';
    protected $db_username = 'root';
    protected $db_password = 'root';
    protected $db_name = 'dbname';
    public function connect() {
        $connect_db = new mysqli($this->db_server, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_name);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connection failed!", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "connected";
        }
        return true;
    }
    function arr() {
        $conn = $this->connect();
        if($query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users")) {
            echo 'row is ' . mysqli_num_rows($query);
        }
    }
}
$db = new DB();
$db->arr();
```

result -> "connected row is " not count rows

Comment: Your `connect` method does not return the connection object

Comment: You should also store the connection and return the same one if you call the `connect()` method multiple times. The way you now have it now, a new connection will be created each time you call `connect()`, which just creates an overhead (connections are costly).

Answer (score -1):

In the `connect()` function, change

```
return true;
```

to

```
return $connect_db;
```

so that it returns the connection object. Then you can use it in your other functions.

Comment: return $connect_db; :D

Comment: @Pirune sorry yes I wrote it in a hurry. I always call my connection objects `$conn`, it's just a habit. I have updated the answer :-)